# How to setup mixed (Linux/Windows) Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, installation

I have a remote Debian machine with a Cassandra datacenter and I would like to replicate the data I have to a second machine, which only has Windows on it. I do not have full control over this machine e.g I cannot install new operating system.

The first question: is it possible? I found only one reference, but that was strongly against the mixed clusters.

If it is possible, is there anything special I have to bear in my mind in comparison with a normal (Windows/Windows or Linux/Linux) replication setup?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to mix different operating systems in a single cluster as per this article:

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/questions-from-the-tokyo-cassandra-conference

"Cassandra does not support mixing different operating systems in a single cluster: you can have (for instance) a Windows cluster, and a Linux cluster, but not a mixed Windows/Linux cluster."

Comment: Yes, I found this too, it is quite old (from 2011) but originally made me think. I also asked this question in the apache cassandra IRC, they said they do not see any issue and I should try to set up the mixed cluster. I just cannot believe that I am the first one, who runs into this problem.

Comment: I think it warrants a quick smoke test. As you said there is not much documentation on the matter. It's a unique use-case.

Answer (score 0):

For the closure: I ended up installing Linux on the local machine, as it seemed the best solution.